# Getting error in Windows 8 OS

Tags: windows-8

While I use my PC, it suddenly restart with an alert (Your PC ran into a problem). After restart it give a message of PC ran in problem.

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z5QIo.jpg]

please help me out.

Comment: You should copy the pertinent information from the error report here.

Comment: You have a BSOD (bugcheck). share the dmp file from C:\Windows\Minidump so that we can check them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1)Click "Send Details" - this will send a copy of your dump files to microsoft.  They will not respond personally, but use this information when building windows patches.

2)Open the windows event viewer (Control panel > small icons > administrative tools > event viewer) and look for critical or error events.

3)Try uninstalling any new software you have installed recently (including AV, windows updates etc)

4)Unplug any new hardware which you have installed and could be causing problems

5)Try a full antivirus, anti spyware, anti malware (etc) scan and see what you find to clean up

Steps 2-5 may require you to boot into safe mode to accomplish this.  (see http://www.howtogeek.com/107511/how-to-boot-into-safe-mode-on-windows-8-the-easy-way/) or restart your PC and keep tapping F8 before selecting Safe mode